# Gigabit Ethernet takes ~370ms to report link down in MII register

Tags: delay, ethernet, loss, nic, carrier

To give you some context, I am trying to configure some network redundancy on Ubuntu 20.04.
I decided to use NIC bonding with:

- 2 Gigabit interfaces,
- active-backup mode,
- link state monitoring with MII (polling every 10ms).

It works as expected, when the active slave fails (wire unplugged) the bonding switches to the other slave. **However this transition is too slow in my opinion as it takes up to 400ms.**

In order to investigate I had a look at the MII register using this command: `mii-tool -vv ens33` (*-vv* is to print raw MII registers content). It generates this kind of output:

[image]

Doing a basic bash script I print current time + value of the 2nd MII register which contains the link state. As this is a "*while true*" loop with no pause, I get a status every 20ms, so it allows me monitoring with enough reactivity.

**Observed behavior**:

1. when the interfaces are configured with a 100Mbit/s speed, Full Duplex => the MII register is almost immediately updated (no "visible" delay between the wire unplugging and the update of the register value on the screen).
2. however when configured at 1Gbit/s, Full Duplex (via auto-negotiation) => the update of MII register takes much more time (it is "visible" with the bash script). By sending pings every 10ms using the bond interface, and logging packets with Wireshark on receiver side, the observed delay is around 370ms.

**My questions**:

The Ethernet controler is an Intel I210, and I have not found anything relevant in the datasheet.

- Do you see any reason for such a long time to detect link down when interface speed is 1Gbit/s vs 100Mbit/s (370 vs 50ms) ?
- Any advice to improve the reactivity?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every generation of Ethernet speed has it's own method and requirements.

- **10BaseT**:
  "link pulses" are used every 16 ±8 ms
- **100BaseT**: "link pulses" are not used but Idle ("/I/") 4B/5B code words monitoring is instead.
- **1000BaseT**: link failure is actually
  determined by maxwait_timer which is defined in IEEE 802.3 to be 750 ±10 ms for Master and 350 ±10
  ms for Slave ports.

As you can see, your measured 370ms are exactly what you can expect from a slave port.

Sources:

- https://www.microchip.com/forums/FindPost/417307
- https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/VPPD-03240.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, this perfectly explains my figures. I let the question open in case someone see some area of improvement to "tune" this behavior.